# Barba JS - Script added via hook isn't available when new container enters after page transition

Tags: barbajs, alpine.js

I'm using Barba js and alpine to create page transitions. I'm trying to add specific js scripts to a container before it transitions in, but I can't seem to get it right.

I've been trying to use Barba hooks to add the script and then firing a custom event upon entering to trigger alpine into running the code. The script gets added and alpine get's triggered, but doesn't seem to be there in time for alpine. If I add a delay then it works fine. I was wondering if there was a way of preloading a script and attaching it to the next container before the transition? Making sure that the script has actually completed loading before transitioning?

This is what I'm doing at the moment.

```
// Function to load scripts for specific partials
function addScripts(container) {
   // add page scripts
   // get all scripts to load
   var allScripts = container.querySelectorAll('.barba_load_script'), 
       i;
   for (i = 0; i < allScripts.length; i++) {
       console.log("Loading Script: " + allScripts[i].getAttribute('data-script-src'));
       let script = document.createElement('script');
       script.src = allScripts[i].getAttribute('data-script-src');
       container.appendChild(script);
   }
}

barba.init({
   transitions: [{
   async leave(data) {
      await pageTransitionIn()
      data.current.container.remove();
   },
   async enter(data) {
      // await delay(1000); // adding this gives it enough time to work, it's obviously bad practice
      await pageTransitionOut(data.next.container)
   },
   async once(data) {
      // await delay(1000);
      await contentAnimation(data.next.container);
   }
}]

barba.hooks.before((data) => {
   // add page scripts
   addScripts(data.next.container);
});
barba.hooks.beforeOnce((data) => {
   // add page scripts
   addScripts(data.next.container);
});
```

My html code looks like this

```
<div class="example" id="example" @barbaload.window="example()"></div>
<div class="hidden barba_load_script" data-script-src="example.js"></div>
```

the example() call runs some code which works perfectly if included as a normal script tag on the first page load, but if it's on a page that transitions in then it doesn't work at all. Loading it via this method works on every page load but only with a manually added delay which isn't a solution. The code is quite bulky (it's exported lottie animation code in this instance) so I was really hoping to be able to add it only to pages that need it. I did see that it's being worked on (https://github.com/barbajs/barba/issues/485) but that doesn't seem to have happened yet.